# Iterative Maximization Algorithm

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Here is the problem I am currently trying to solve.

There is a maximum value called T. There are then two subvalues, A and B, that are 1 <= A,B <= T. In each round, you can pick either A or B to add to your sum. You can also choose to half that sum entirely in only one of the rounds. You can never exceed T in any round. Given an infinite number of rounds, what is the maximum sum you can get.

Here's an example:
T = 8
A = 5, B = 6

Solution: We first take B, then half the sum getting 3. Then we add A and get 8. So the maximum possible is 8.

The iterative idea I have come up with is: it is basically a tree structure where you keep branching of and trying to build of older sums. I am having trouble trying to figure out a maximization formula.

Is there a brute force solution that will run fast or is there some elegant formula?

Limits: 1 <= A, B <= T. T <= 5,000,000.

EDIT: When you divide, you round down the sum (i.e. 5/2 becomes 2).

Comment: Are there any limits on `A` other than it being greater than or equal to `1` ?

Comment: The limits are the following. 1 <= A, B <= T. and the limit on T is that it is T <= 5,000,000

Comment: A,B,T are integer only or float ? If it's integer how you round 5/2 ?

Comment: You round down the division. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be viewed as a directed graph with `T + 1` nodes. Imagine we have `T + 1` nodes from 0 to `T`, and we have an edge from node `x` to node `y` if:

- x + A = y
- x + B = y
- x/2 = y

So, in order to answer the question, we need to do a search in the graph, with stating point is node `0`.

We can do either a [breath first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to solve the problem.

**Update**: as we can only do divided once, so we have to add another state to the graph, which is `isDivided`. However, the way to solve this problem is not changed.

I will demonstrate the solution with a BFS implementation, DFS is very similar.

```
class State{
    int node, isDivided;
}

boolean[][]visited = new boolean[2][T + 1];
Queue<State> q = new LinkedList();
q.add(new State(0, 0));//Start at node 0, and haven't use division
visited[0][0] = true;
int result = 0;
while(!q.isEmpty()){
    State state = q.deque();
    result = max(state.node, result);
    if(state.node + A <= T && !visited[state.isDivided][state.node + A]){
          q.add(new State(node + A , state.isDivided));
          visited[state.isDivided][node + A] = true;
    }
    if(node + B <= T && !visited[state.isDivided][node + B]){
          q.add(new State(node + B, state.isDivided));
          visited[state.isDivided][node + B] = true;
    }
    if(state.isDivided == 0 && !visited[state.isDivided][node/2]){
          q.add(new State(node/2, 1));
          visited[state.isDivided][node/2] = true;
    }
}
return result;
```

Time complexity is O(n)

Comment: you are only allowed to divide at most once. will this still work?

Comment: @user3188300 the result is added to the queue, so it is not only divided once. Imagine you add 5 into the queue, so next step, we add (5/2 = 2) into the queue. And some steps after that, we will process 2 (which is already in the queue), then we will add (2/2 = 1) to the queue.

Comment: What I was asking is that in the problem statement, you are only allowed to divide by 2 once overall. You can't keep dividing by 2. For example, once I go to 5/2 = 2. I can no longer divide this sum.

Comment: @user3188300 I see, so actually, we need to add another dimension to the solution, which is `isDivided`. The way to solve it is not much different. Wait for my edit :)

Comment: So we have two graphs, one for divided case, and another for not divided yet?

Comment: @justhalf actually, it is just a giant graph with `2*(T + 1)` nodes, as we have edge between those two states (from not divided to divided), so view this as two separated graphs is not so precise (IMO).

Comment: @PhamTrung this can be solved a lot faster. Actually the algorithm described in the problem can be described by a simple non-recursive function

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your problem setting as I understand it (under the constraint that you can divide by two no more than once):

1. Add `A` and `B` as many times as you want (including 0 each)
2. Divide by 2, rounding down
3. Add `A` and `B` as many times as you want

The goal is to obtain the largest possible sum, subject to the constraint that the sum is no more than `T` after any step of the algorithm.

This can be captured neatly in a 5-variable integer program. The five variables are:

- `a1`: The number of times we add `A` before dividing by 2
- `b1`: The number of times we add `B` before dividing by 2
- `s1`: `floor((A*a1+B*b1)/2)`, the total sum after the second step
- `a2`: The number of times we add `A` after dividing by 2
- `b2`: The number of times we add `B` after dividing by 2

The final sum is `s1+A*a2+B*b2`, which is constrained not to exceed `T`; this is what we seek to maximize. All five decision variables must be non-negative integers.

This integer program can be easily solved to optimality by an integer programming solver. For instance, here is how you would solve it with the `lpSolve` package in R:

```
library(lpSolve)
get.vals <- function(A, B, T) {
  sol <- lp(direction = "max",
            objective.in = c(0, 0, 1, A, B),
            const.mat = rbind(c(A, B, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, A, B), c(-A, -B, 2, 0, 0), c(-A, -B, 2, 0, 0)),
            const.dir = c("<=", "<=", "<=", ">="),
            const.rhs = c(T, T, 0, -1),
            all.int = TRUE)$solution
  print(paste("Add", A, "a total of", sol[1], "times and add", B, "a total of", sol[2], "times for sum", A*sol[1]+B*sol[2]))
  print(paste("Divide by 2, yielding value", sol[3]))
  print(paste("Add", A, "a total of", sol[4], "times and add", B, "a total of", sol[5], "times for sum", sol[3]+A*sol[4]+B*sol[5]))
}
```

Now we can compute how to get as high of a total sum as possible without exceeding T:

```
get.vals(5, 6, 8)
# [1] "Add 5 a total of 1 times and add 6 a total of 0 times for sum 5"
# [1] "Divide by 2, yielding value 2"
# [1] "Add 5 a total of 0 times and add 6 a total of 1 times for sum 8"
get.vals(17, 46, 5000000)
# [1] "Add 17 a total of 93 times and add 46 a total of 0 times for sum 1581"
# [1] "Divide by 2, yielding value 790"
# [1] "Add 17 a total of 294063 times and add 46 a total of 3 times for sum 4999999"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can describe the problem in this way aswell:

```
f(A , B) = (A * n + B * m) / 2 + (A * x + B * y) 
         = A * (n * 0.5 + x) + B * (m * 0.5 + y) =
         = A * p + B * q
find N: N = f(A , B) and N <= T such that no M: M > N satisfying  
the condition exists.
```

The case without any division by two can easily be represented by `n = m = 0` and is thus aswell covered by `f`.

`n` and `y` can be any arbitrary values matching `p = n * 0.5 + y` (same for `q` and related values). Note that there are multiple valid solutions as shown in `f`.

```
T >= A * p + B * q
r = p * 2, s = q * 2
find integral numbers r, s satisfying the condition
T >= A * r / 2 + B * s / 2

simplify:
T * 2 / B >= A / B * r + s
```

Thus we know:

```
(T / B * 2) mod 1 - (A / B * r) mod 1 is minimal and >= 0 for the optimal solution
T * 2 / A >= r >= 0 are the upper and lower bounds for r
(A / B * r) mod 1 = 0, if r = B / gcd(A , B) * n, where n is an integral number
```

Finding r using these constraints now becomes a trivial task, using binary search. There might be more efficient approach to this, but `O(log B)` should do for this purpose:

```
    Apply a simple binary-search to find the matching value  
    in the range [0 , min(T * 2 / A , B / gcd(A , B))
```

Finding `s` can easily be done for any corresponding `r`:

```
s = roundDown(T * 2 / B - A * r / B)
```

E.g.:

```
A = 5
B = 6
T = 8

gcd(A , B) = 1
search-range = [0 , 6)
(T / B * 2) mod 1 = 4 / 6

(A / B * r) mod 1 = 
    r = 3: 3 / 6 => too small --> decrease r
    r = 1: 5 / 6 => too great --> increase r
    r = 2: 4 / 6 => optimal solution, r is found

r = 2
s = roundDown(T * 2 / B - A * r / B) = roundDown(3.2 - 1.66) = 1

p = r / 2 = 1 = 1 + 0 = 2 * 0.5  --> n = 1 y = 0 or n = 2 y = 0
q = s / 2 = 0.5                  --> n = 0.5 y = 0

8 >= 5 * 1 + 5 * 0.5 * 0 + 0 * 6 + 1 * 0.5 * 6 = 5 + 3 
   = 5 * 0 + 5 * 0.5 * 2 + 0 * 6 + 1 * 0.5 * 6 = 5 + 3
```

Advantage of this approach: We can find **all** solutions in `O(log B)`:
If a value for r is found, all other values r' matching the constraints are as follows: `r' = r + B / gcd(A , B) * n`. `A` and `B` are exchangeable in this approach allowing to optimize even further by using the smaller input value as `B`.

The rounding of values when the variable is divided by two in your algorithm should only cause minor problems, which can easily be fixed.

Comment: A good approach. Btw, how do you represent that at any point during the whole iterations, the sum cannot exceed T? I think it should be something like `A*m + B*n <= T`, but I don't see that in your answer. Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: @justhalf It's in the redefinition of the problem and afterwards in the calculations (`T >= A * p + B * q` for eg., 4th line of the example)?

Comment: I see, perhaps you can include that in your problem re-description as well.

Comment: Look nice, can you provide some document about your approximation method :) ?

Comment: @PhamTrung I actually made a mistake about the approximation - needed a bit of sleep. It's by far more complex than i thought. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @PhamTrung I've updated the answer with an algorithm for the approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use some mathematical approach.

Resume:

You should be able to calculate the max with A,B, T, without iterations (only to get A/B HCD), for T, not to small.

- If A or B is an odd number, max = T (with a reserve, I'm not sure you never go over T: see below).
- If A **and** B is even numbers, get C as highest common factor. Then max = round (T/C*2) *C/2  = highest multiple of C/2 below or equal to T

Some explanations:

With the rule: A*p+B*q  (without dividing by 2)

1 suppose A and B are primes together, then you can get every integer you want, after the little ones. Then max=T

example: A=11, B=17

2 if A=C*x, and B=C*y, x,y primes together (like 10 and 21), you can get every C multiples, then max= biggest multiple of C below T: round(T/C)*C

example: A=33, B=51 (C=3)

With the rule : you can divide by 2

3 - If C is even number (that is A and B can be divided by 2): max= multiple of C/2 below T: round(T/C*2)*C/2

example: A=22, B=34 (C=2)

4 - Otherwise, you have to find the biggest dividor (highest common factor) of A, B, round(A/2), round (B/2), call it D, max= biggest multiple of D below T: round(T/D)*D
As A and round (A/2) are primes together (idem for B and round (B/2)), then you can get max = T as in case 1 - warning: I'm not sure if you never go past T. To check